# How to find out how many characters came before image tag using Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, rubygems, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am trying to recreate the text for comment messages given in a website I am scraping, but am having trouble handling the case where the text has images in between the text. The images are the smiley emoticons.

For example, the following comment would appear as the HTML underneath (pretending the "alt" is the true image)

```
text text text blah blah blah :3some more text that will come directly after

<div>
    "text text text blah blah blah "
    <img src="/smiley.png" width="16" height="16" alt=":3" title>
    "some more text that will come directly after"
</div>
```

I was hoping there was a way to could the number of characters before `<img ...>` to use the String's `insert()` method to insert the alt-text with the message itself.

Anyone have any other ideas or know how to implement such a solution?

---

When I call `inspect` on the div element, I get the following:

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fda6dc527cc name="div" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fda6dc52484 "text text text blah blah blah ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fda6dc523a8 name="img" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fda6dc52330 name="src" value="/smiley.png">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fda6dc52308 name="width" value="16">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fda6dc522b8 name="height" value="16">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fda6dc522a4 name="alt" value=":3">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fda6d487470 "some more text that will come directly after">]>]
```

Which I didn't know I could do before posting this. I'm betting that the children list/array can be accessed individually?

---

I ended up turning this div element into a string and using parsing to get what I wanted.

If anyone has a more elegant solution, let me know! I am all for learning more about it.

Comment: What have your tried? For example, if get the grid content, what is the output ?

Comment: I'm not sure what grid content is, but I think I may have found a solution. Do you mind explaining what grid content is for some learning experience?

Comment: Sorry. I meant div and wrote grid. Really sry for the mistake.

Comment: That what you just posted in your edit is what I was going for. As you can see you have 3 children. Two texts and one Element. I don't know much about nokogiri but I think you can filter the type of child you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand.  Sounds like you want to take that original HTML and replace all image tags with their alt text?  If so, this will work:

```
> html = '<div>
*     text text text blah blah blah
*     <img src="/smiley.png" width="16" height="16" alt=":3" title>
*     some more text that will come directly after
* </div>'

> doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)
> doc.css('img').each {|img| img.replace(img.attr('alt'))}

> puts doc.at('div').text

    text text text blah blah blah
    :3
    some more text that will come directly after
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking to do. This is definitely a much better solution than what I had planned on using. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

*How to find out how many characters came before image tag using Nokogiri?*

```
img = doc.at('img')
img.previous.text.length
```